# Emacs project management for Scala

Tags: scala, emacs, sbt, ensime

I would like to ask if any of you have any experience {and,or} could point me to a project management extension for Emacs that works well with {Scala,Ensime,SBT}. It would also be amazing if it didn't require too much hacking. I did some scheme in the past but I have little experience with the Emacs platform.

Basically, by project management I mean mainly the ability to 'tie files into project' and then search among them (and only among them).

Thanks for taking the time to read this and answer!

Comment: You will likely get better answers if you are more specific about your question.

Comment: Ok, i reworked my question. Removed all the fluff, hopefully it's better now :)

Answer (score 2):

> I really hate that you can't setup projects out of the box, though.

Just set up the project with sbt or maven and import it with ensime.

> Essentially, what i would want is to be able to flex-find files in the project

"flex-find" is not English, so I don't really know what you mean. But what is wrong with `find` (the command line tool)?

Answer (score 1):

With ensime you can load your project and then [search for a type or method](http://aemon.com/file_dump/ensime_manual.html#tth_sEc4.8) by name. The key sequence is *C-c C-v v*. This allows you to, for example, jump directly to a class definition.

Comment: Hmm, is there any way to jump into the source the class is in?

Comment: Yes, it jumps into the source when you hit <enter>. (Maybe you need to configure Ensime with the top-level source directory?)

Comment: hmm, it only shows to me the class api (methods, traits etc.) I will tinker with it for a bit. Thanks a lot for the answer though, it's pretty much what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The package `projectile` has a bunch of generic project-level features, such as running commands in the project root folder, grepping, creating `TAGS` files etc.

I'm a relatively new user of it, so I can't say exactly how big a difference it makes, but it seems like a worthwhile addition to your tool belt.